# Error when attempting to migrate to postgres database on Heroku from Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, sinatra

I have deployed my Sinatra application to Heroku. I have a sqlite database but since Heroku requires postgres, I needed to change this. To do this I setup a Postgres database on Heroku and specified separate development and production databases in my database.yml file.

```
 development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite
  pool: 5

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production
  pool: 5
```

I also changed the code in my environment file:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
 
  configure :development do
  ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"
 
  require 'bundler/setup'
  Bundler.require(:default, ENV['SINATRA_ENV'])
 
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database => "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.sqlite"
   )
  end
 
  configure :production do
   db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/production')
  
   puts "db is: #{db}"

   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
     :host     => db.host,
     :username => db.user,
     :password => db.password,
     :database => db.path[1..-1],
     :encoding => 'utf8'
   )
  end

require_all 'app'
```

The error message that I receive is as follows:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I'm not sure why it appears to be attempting to connect to localhost? I have tried specifying the host listed in my heroku database credentials but I still receive the same message. I can see the application deployed in heroku, I just can't log in. This application does work locally.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you double-check that `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is actually set?

Comment: I have ENV['DATABASE_URL'] ||= the URI in my database credentials in the heroku database in my .env file. I'm not sure if that is correct?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to manually set `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` it should be set automatically by Heroku when you app a database to your application. Check if it is set on our application on Heroku -> "Settings" tab -> then click "Reveal Config Vars"

Comment: It is set under Reveal Config Vars. So I do not need to set DATABASE_URL to anything in the .env file? I was just able to migrate the database using                                                                 
   heroku pg:promote DATABASE_URL. Now I am just having trouble seeding it.

Comment: Seems that Postgres wants a limit to integer size? ActiveModel::RangeError: 3123456789 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes

Comment: Fixed the error that I was getting when trying to seed the database by writing migration files to change the :int columns to :bigint.